# Why does this code break once "app" and the ng-controller are added?

Tags: angularjs

This code is virtually verbatim from egghead.io, but it is not working at all unless I remove `="app"` and remove the `ng-controller` attribute from the `<body>` element.  (And of course the last `<script>` element gets ignored in the process—the code that would normally be in `app.js`.)  Of course removing those bits prevents anything else from working or being added.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-ui-router-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
      .controller("FirstCtrl", function FirstCtrl() {
        var first = this;
        first.greeting = "First";
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="FirstCtrl as first">
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="first.greeting" placeholder="First Name">
      <hr>
      <h1>{{ first.greeting }} World!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's [similar code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sr6fmxq/1/). (It's only similar because JSFiddle imposes constraints that make it impossible to post identical code.  It has the same problem, so I assume the differences are insignificant for tracking down the source of the bug.)

Where is the bug?  Why is this not working?

Comment: angular 1.0.0 is an **ancient** version, which isn't officially supported and didn't offer some of the features used in this example.  Also, not only is there not a 1.0.0 version of angular-ui-router, but that particular library isn't even written by the angular team, and wouldn't be in their code repository.  if you fix your scripts and use current versions, you should be fine.

Comment: Updating to 1.4.8 didn't change anything.  Removing or updating ui-router didn't either.

Comment: this is partially due to how JSFiddle works.  In JSFiddle, you have to click the little gear next to "JavaScript" and ensure that it is set to `NoWrap - In <Head>` rather than the default of `onload`.  I forked a working fiddle that has 1.4.8, removed ui-router, and changed to nowrap, which works properly. https://jsfiddle.net/bvj7eg61/

Comment: just a side note - because of how JSFiddle handles scripts and the need to change this setting, I actually prefer working in http://plnkr.co/ with angular.

Comment: Change Angular and UI-router dependency to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

With latest angular dependency it worked for me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
      .controller("FirstCtrl", function FirstCtrl() {
        var first = this;
        first.greeting = "First";
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="FirstCtrl as first">
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="first.greeting" placeholder="First Name">
      <hr>
      <h1>{{ first.greeting }} World!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular ui-router but not using it the way you are supposed to be. Check the [**documentation**](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) here to get a clearer idea. Angular UI router loads its contents in a container containing `ui-view` attribute. As per documentation

> AngularUI Router is a routing framework for AngularJS, which allows you to organize the parts of your interface into a state machine. Unlike the $route service in Angular core, which is organized around URL routes, UI-Router is organized around states, which may optionally have routes, as well as other behavior, attached.

You need to load different states in your ui-view and also pass values in different states in the process. You need to add dependencies for `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider` in your app config for a completely functional angular ui router implementation. This being told what you need to do is like below -

> And also check out the working example in [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AX0IlxuI4nCSzUxXycgc?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
<title>AngularJS: UI-Router Quick Start</title>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
  <div class="well" ui-view></div>        
</div>
</div>         

<!-- Angular -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
<!-- UI-Router -->
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<!-- App Script -->
<script>
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")

  $stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        templateUrl: "route1.html",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.greeting = "First";
          }
    })
 })
</script>

</body>

</html>
```